# Rails + Sunspot: "Unassigned" facet for filtering records that don't have an association assigned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, faceted-search

Still learning about facets, but I would like to filter for records that do not have an associated record assigned. First some code:

The model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  searchable do
    text :name
    integer :category_id, :references => Category
  end
end
```

The controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Project.search do
      fulltext params[:q]
      facet :category_id
      with(:category_id, params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id].present?
    end
    @projects = @search.results
    respond_with(@projects)
  end
```

The view:

```
<ul>
  <% for row in @search.facet(:category_id).rows %>
    <li>
      <% if params[:category_id].blank? %>
        <%= link_to row.instance.name, :category_id => row.value %> (<%= row.count %>)
      <% else %>
        <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :category_id => nil %>)
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The view shows a list of category filters with their respective counts, however, I want to include an "Unassigned" facet **(and its count)** which will query projects that have not been assigned a category. Is this possible with facets? Also, what about an "Assigned any" facet (and its count) that filters projects that have been assigned *any* category? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since you asked this question. But I've recently been working with rails/sunspot/solr, and stumbled upon your question. Hopefully you've found your answer, but if not, here's how I would do it.

Facets are a way to categorize the current search results. One way to get the "Unassigned" facet implemented, is to actually index the objects with it.

In your Project Model, I would change it to:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  searchable do
    text :name
    string :category_name do
      category_id.present? ? (category.name + "|" + category_id.to_s) : "Unassigned"
    end
  end
end
```

I see you're using `row.instance.name` in the view to get the category name. Because I've switched the searchable attribute to a string (and for obvious reasons, you can't use `:references` and `row.instance` with a string value!) I've chosen to index the field with a combination of the `category_name|category_id` type field. If the `Project` does not have a `category_id`, the string `"Unassigned"` is used.

Now we change the code in your search block to reflect or model changes.

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Project.search do
      fulltext params[:q]
      facet :category_name
      with(:category_name, params[:category_name]) if params[:category_name].present?
    end
    @projects = @search.results
    respond_with(@projects)
  end
```

and the view code changes as well:

```
<ul>
  <% for row in @search.facet(:category_name).rows %>
    <li>
      <% if params[:category_name].blank? %>
        <%= link_to (row.value.include? '|') ? row.value.split('|')[0] : row.value, :category_name => row.value %> (<%= row.count %>)
      <% else %>
        <strong><%= row.value %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :category_name => nil %>)
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```